# Origin of POSSLQ

Tags: etymology

I looked up the etymology of this on [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=POSSLQ&searchmode=none), but it doesn't state the origin. It only defines what it stood for. It did tell what its date of origin is however, but that isn't what I was looking for.

Can someone please tell me its origin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSSLQ):

> POSSLQ ( /ˈpɒsəlkjuː/) is an abbreviation (or acronym) for "Persons of Opposite Sex Sharing Living Quarters," a term coined in the late 1970s by the United States Census Bureau as part of an effort to more accurately gauge the prevalence of cohabitation in American households.

And [Dictionary Online](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/posslq) seems to agree, at least about users of this acronym

Comment: Romantic bunch those census guys!

Comment: @Martin - I've been using this term for years - originally ironically, and later because I found it to be the most concise way to convey the information without making any assumptions.  "Roommates" implies that there is no sexual/romantic relationship; "live-in boyfriend/girlfriend" implies that there is.  I made the wrong assumption once or twice in each direction before deciding to use POSSLQ as a neutral term from then on.